# Git Subtrees vs Composer

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, git-subtree

This may be a pretty naive question, but I am trying to understand the difference in utility between Git's Subtree and Composer dependency management for PHP. I started using Git Subtrees after dumping Git Submodules. But now there is Composer (for PHP). As most of my projects are PHP based, I am thinking of dumping Subtrees in favor of Composer.

For example, I have multiple Wordpress sites. I would like to pull Wordpress itself and the plugins I want to use. I can achieve that with both Git Subtrees and Composer, right?

IF I don't have a use-case to commit/push code in a sub-folder upstream, but only wish to pull the latest/specific version into the sub-folder, do Subtree and Composer provide the same kind of utility?

In my use case, I feel that Composer trumps Git Subtree by being easier to use, easier to get another/newer version of a script in a sub-folder, without getting those pulled sub-folder files committed into Git repo.

Any thoughts on this understanding of mine? Is there a problem in this sort of strategy? Or both of them are totally different and don't have any similarities?

Comment: I'd simply express it like this: git subtrees are tied to you using git as a versioning system. You cannot migrate only the files elsewhere, you will always have to keep the whole project as a git repository and you happen to use on of its minor features for 3rd party dependency management. On the other hand, Composer is a tool specifically for the purpose of managing 3rd party dependencies, independently of any other system. The choice seems pretty clear to me, but it's really up to you in the end.

Comment: Even if you need to edit code in a dependency, you can do so by getting it as source "composer update somedependency --prefer-source". You are then able to edit the code for both the project and the dependency at the same time, and git commit them to their respective repo independently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of reasons favor Composer.

It actually **manages dependencies** of a whole project and vendor libraries themselves. So if you require a package it will get all required stuff or notify you about errors.

**Managing versions** is also trivial, as for every package you download you can specify version it should be updating to (so you can decide to only update minor releases of a package or go full-out with dev-master)

Composer provides some help with **autoloading** too. Making your project a little bit faster when run with `-o`

Having development only packages also allows you to **manage production settings** easier.

I find literally no reason for using submodules if vendor provides composer functionality.